# WooCommerce - Get order cart items quantity ADMIN

Tags: wordpress, admin, woocommerce

This variable works for the template:

```
$woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
```

But doesn't work for admin...

Does anyone know how to get the cart items quantity and display it on the order edition page?

---

```
/**
* Display field value on the order edition page
**/
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address','my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
 // doesn't work...
 echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cart's classes aren't loaded in the dashboard area by default.

Probably, you need to display number of products that are in the order you're editing now. In that case you should use  `$order->get_item_count()` function in your "my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta".

But if you really need to get cart items of current logged in user (admin), you should load all cart contents from session manually:

```
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta(WC_Order $order){
    global $woocommerce;

    include_once( $woocommerce->plugin_path . '/classes/abstracts/abstract-wc-session.php' ); // Abstract for session implementations
    include_once( $woocommerce->plugin_path . '/classes/class-wc-session-handler.php' );    // WC Session class

    $session_class = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_session_handler', 'WC_Session_Handler' );
    $woocommerce->session = new $session_class();
    $woocommerce->cart = new WC_Cart();
    $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_from_session();

    echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count; //here it is

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
```